# preload photos from folders into cache javascript / php

Tags: javascript, php, caching

I have a photography website with many albums ( around 10 ) and for a better user experience on site I would like to load all the photos in to cache memory when user enters the website. Any ideas ?

Comment: while once upon a time this was a good idea, with current internet speeds in weary of this approach

Comment: **5,038 possible duplicates**, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=preload+images did you use the search?

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this using the html5 feature "Application Cache"

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp